# Godot - Staticbody3d collision normal issue

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am having problem figure out how the normal work.
I am using `godot4 RC1`.
I created a `staticbody3D` and want to place a 3dobject standing upright like how we stand on earth.
this is my code for the staticbody3d:

```
func _on_input_event(camera, event, position, normal, shape_idx):
    player.global_position = position
    var q = Quaternion.from_euler(normal)
    player.basis = q
```

basically I use the code to capture the mouse_over `position` on the `staticbody3d` and place my `player(Mesh3d)` at the position, and align the `player` basis to the `normal`.
if mouse at the top of the planet, it turn out ok.
[image: correct normal]

but anywhere else, it just gone hay wire:
[image: wrong]
[image: wrong]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I found the solution, so I posted it here for future reference:
http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3.x/3d/3d_align_surface/